# Comma Community release 2020.07.0 sun/javafx/PlatformUtil problem

Tags: javafx, raku, macos-catalina, commaide, intellij-idea-2020

### Update (2020-11-03)

The issue described in the original post is resolved. I have no problems running Raku scripts with:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3
- [Comma Community release 2020.10.0](https://commaide.com/download)

### Original post

I program in Raku and I am trying to use [Comma Community release 2020.07.0](https://commaide.com/download) with IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 and 2020.2.1 (Community Edition) on Mac OS 10.15.6.

When I try to run a configured script I am getting the error "Error running 'Examples': com/sun/javafx/PlatformUtil" :

[image: Commaide-error-when-script-running]

I did numerous searches on the web to find suggestions to fix this and nothing I tried worked. So, I reverted to using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4 .

Any suggestions how to get Commaide working in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 ?

Comment: I see there's been a new release today of IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2, namely IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1. Perhaps you mean that, and even if not, I don't see any obvious bug match in [the release notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2020.2.1+(202.6948.69+build)+Release+Notes?_ga=2.262407628.198906938.1598367959-864337054.1597693364). But it would be helpful to check if the problem goes away with that, or at least clarify if you have checked 2020.2.1 and it still has this problem. (I don't know how you upgrade IntelliJ. I'm not currently a Comma user, nor MacOS.)

Comment: @raiph Thanks for prompting me for the new IntelliJ release. (It was released today, and I did try to update IntelliJ before posting.) I still get the error with IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1.

Comment: I've added tags that I think correctly narrow things to your specific system setup. Please alter them if I'm wrong. They may attract attention from IntelliJ folk who either see the same problem in other IDEA plugins or IDEA based products, or otherwise know enough to be helpful and comment here. If not, it'll be down to Comma folk looking into it or working with you to do so. I think I've done the best I can. Thanks for posting and good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's probably not much to be done other than waiting for a newer Comma release.

Ideally, the Comma plugin would Just Work against newer versions of IntelliJ. While JetBrains mostly do a good job of retaining compatibility, or at least of deprecating things in one release and removing them in a later release so there's a chance to keep up, experience tells that if one is touching enough of the platform, there will often be something or other that gets broken by updates. Comma uses a significant amount of the IntelliJ platform API, and evidently something it depended on has changed in an incompatible way.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer!

Comment: FWIW, I got a very similar issue on a machine that had a fresh install on Java dev tools, but running standalone Comma.  Not at that computer for another day or two, but I'll submit an issue with details (and reminds me I need to renew my subscription for Comma++)